# Do I need to annotate object properties both in class and interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am starting using TypeScript and have this question about BP in annotating classes.

So, example:

```
interface PluginManagerInterface {
    _plugins: {
        [name: string]: {
            [status: string]: boolean
        }
    }
}

class PluginManager implements PluginManagerInterface {

    _plugins: {
        [key: string]: {
            [status: string]: boolean
        }
    }

    constructor() {
        this._plugins = {};
    }

    // ...code
}
```

Do I need here to copy-paste `_plugins` variable annotation to class from interface? Or am I using annotation wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to write the types in the class again. Typescript will not infer property types based on `implements` clauses. So if you don't specify the type it will be `any` by default. `implements` will only check that the class properties can be an implementation for the interface (and a property with type `any` will match any type in the interface).

You can put the complex type in a dedicated interface, or you can use type queries:

```
interface PluginManagerInterface {
    _plugins: {
        [name: string]: {
            [status: string]: boolean
        }
    }
}

class PluginManager implements PluginManagerInterface {

    _plugins: PluginManagerInterface['_plugins']

    constructor() {
        this._plugins = {};
    }

    // ...code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I mean you can just make a type or an interface out of it:

```
interface Plugins {
  [name: string]: {
    [status: string]: boolean;
  };
}

interface PluginManagerInterface {
  _plugins: Plugins;
}

class PluginManager implements PluginManagerInterface {
  _plugins: Plugins;

  constructor() {
    this._plugins = {};
  }

  // ...code
}
```